# Client-side typescript: how do I remove circular dependencies from the factory method pattern?

Tags: javascript, typescript, design-patterns, circular-dependency, rollup

I am using the [factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) in some of my code. The problem is, some of those instances also use the same factory method pattern. This creates circular dependencies and I can't think of a way of removing them. Let me give [an example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKA9GAEBmCGDGAXA9gJwJ4FkCmiAWyAJgHSIDOoAlgLYAOaikAkgHZmKwvzYCMMqyapADkxMK3aduPYQG4qdBszYcu2AEz9BIsRNXd1chfVSM9U7AGYtQ0eJUXLRkDROMA3sslqANF-3YAHKw1NiQAL42Ovbe3M6g2AAebpDwyCqQAOa45moAQujBoZAAvJAAFKCQkJQOakXYAFz+Fg2gAJTNudylAHyQ7lWQZADulIjweBW1sUEh2O0DQ9XwsGRhwt28wo3L1ZCouACuqCwtajzyIPupaxtbhrvXNwfHp+cGVzer6yJbTk8Xq9ECczv8vvtCNg4EcADaIQEvfACEaQFjYVEAUVQAlQ5XaEPCoHCV1AEEgSUQh1CsPQAAlsLDaNA4QBVRCUWHjdAAMSOXA56VIFBcilMAyyOTq3AKDQiUTscCQaCwuAIhHiICSKTSGUp1MZ9MZzLZHK5iF5-KQlHSpWm0rmoS6DoanTRR2oACNsKg+ktnuSmNRYJlamF8JQyJARmtIJwKYkqdgaehIHhjSzYZAjmbuTArYKWENDiD3tlEFtZfNyjMAq7iCwPcTQGSoFthQlkkpaogfUqwlt-dVCMgAMqCNW1TLNfF+xten0Q+fNefe1BXIkgTspC20Acu+Z2zYOmSQAA+fwdhnPl9mTlJ4DbJ47opSnn1ycNDKZmfZnO5fICjaZyRNAAi2GIH4pt+Jqwn+5qWkB6Sarq7A1M6sx2oMzwjuOoQRiw04VG6q4+n62E3CWoIJkm0EZqa-4WoB1rpOUx6zIYiwANQ0QatIwb+uZMQWwFsf8wgEpA5LwJQqDwHCsC+lCe4sFCXDoEM4Q+M2WpduKUIwvCNQPuSADy+BkbWFhRgZYaEJA3qwsgIx+OgyBHJKjAWTUUKwMQQA):

```
// factoryMethod.ts
import Instance1 from './Instance1';
import Instance2 from './Instance2';
import Instance3 from './Instance3';
import { Instance, InstanceName } from './Instance';

export const getInstanceByName = (
  instanceName: InstanceName
): Instance => {
  switch (instanceName) {
    case 'Instance1':
      return Instance1;
    case 'Instance2':
      return Instance2;
    case 'Instance3':
      return Instance3;
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
};

// extremelyHelpfulUtilityFunction.ts
import { getInstanceByName } from './factoryMethod';

export const extremelyHelpfulUtilityFunction = (instanceName: InstanceName): number => {
  // Imagine this was an extremely helpful utility function
  return getInstanceByName(instanceName).num
}

// Instance.ts
export interface Instance {
  doSomething: () => number;
  num: number;
}

export type InstanceName = 'Instance1' | 'Instance2' | 'Instance3';

// Instance1.ts
import { extremelyHelpfulUtilityFunction } from './extremelyHelpfulUtilityFunction';

const i: Instance = {
  doSomething: (): number => {
    return extremelyHelpfulUtilityFunction('Instance2') + extremelyHelpfulUtilityFunction('Instance3'); // circular dependency
  },
}
export default i;

// Other instances defined below, you get the idea.
```

I'm using rollup to turn this into a single JavaScript file, and when I do, it warns me that I have a circular dependency. I want to get rid of this warning. I realize the code will still function, but I don't want the warning there. How can I modify this code so that InstanceX can get InstanceY without it being a circular dependency?

Comment: What is the reason for using `extremelyHelpfulUtilityFunction('Instance2')` instead of `new Instance2()` here? `doSomething` does not take any parameters, so the string value is constant.

Comment: if `Instance2's doSomething => extremelyHelpfulUtilityFunction("Instance1") +    extremelyHelpfulUtilityFunction("Instance3")` then it will go into infinite recursion, right?

Comment: @JulienD because the real `extremelyHelpfulUtilityFunction` is extremely complex in the real code.  It does a lot more than that single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO the problem is that `extremelyHelpfulUtilityFunction` has to know `getInstanceByName`, while the result of this factory could always be known in advance by the caller and the desired value passed as argument to the helper.

I would propose

```
// Instance1.ts
const instance1: Instance = {
  doSomething: (): number => {
    return (new Instance2()).toNum() + (new Instance3()).toNum()
  },
}
```

with `toNum` defined in Instance.ts and overridden in its subclasses, using the helper but with proper parameters, for example

```
// Instance2.ts
const instance2: Instance = {
  doSomething: ...,
  toNum: (): number => {
    return extremelyHelpfulUtilityFunction(1234)
  }
}
```

where you would use `this.num` instead of `1234` if you declared a proper class for `Instance2` instead of this object, like

```
// Instance2.ts
class Instance2 extends Instance {
  num = 1234;
  doSomething: ...
  toNum(): number {
    return extremelyHelpfulUtilityFunction(this.num)
  }
}
export default new Instance2();
```

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking the same thing, but I was hoping there was a way I wouldn't have to call `extremelyHelpfulUtilityFunction` in each implementation. I guess this is the expressivity problem. Anyway, I think this solves my problem. I'm going to attempt it before I mark this answer as accepted though